# Unable to create more then one gadget in GateIn portal

Tags: jboss, portal

Repost from: [Jboss GateIn Discussion](http://community.jboss.org/message/535281). Please refer that post for screenshots.

Here what happens when I try to create 2 gadgets:

1. I press "Create a new gadget"
2. Leave content as is and press "Save". As the result gadget gets name "CHANGME" and there is no way to change it.
3. Press "Create a new gadget" and change title to "hello2 ...."
4. Press "Save". New gadget replaces previous gadget in the left menu and gets the same name "CHANGME" with no way to change it

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?
My setup is: JBoss 5.1, GateIn 3.0, Windows Datacenter 2008, Java 1.6

Comment: As mentioned in the forum thread, it's a bug.